# Sklearn train_test_split() error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, numpy

I am fitting a regression model on randomly generated X1,x2 and Y be the sum of x1, x2 but I am getting this error

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 10000000]

**Note:- I am doing this only for learning purposes**

My code:-

```
X = np.random.random_integers(100000000,size=(2,10000000))
X=(X-(100000000/2))/(100000000/2) # Scaling [-1,1]
Y = X[0]+X[1]

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=0)
regr.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the shape of your training data to be `(num_samples, num_features)` or in your case `(10000000, 2)`. An easy way to fix this is to transpose `X` before feeding it to the train test split:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.T, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)  # <-- also 'y_train' not 'Y_train' here
```